# Excel VBA to generate a list of 100 pseudo-random numbers

Tags: excel, random, worksheet-function, vba

```
Dim loop_ctr As Integer
For loop_ctr = 1 To 100
    Sheets("Capacity&Costs").Activate
    Range("TrialOne") = "=INT(RAND()*3+1)-1"
    Calculate

Next loop_ctr
```

Hi, I have the above VBA code. From this point, I would like to obtain a list of all the 100 values from this calculation and display it as a list on a different worksheet. Is that possible? Right now if I run this code, it only displays the value of the 100th calculation.

TrialOne is two columns that contain either 0, 1, or 2. I want to carry out above code 100 times, and record each outcome separately as a list, so I have a list of 100 numbers

Comment: How is your range `TrialOne` defined? And your title asks for "a minimum value" and your text asks about obtaining a list of 100 values - which is it? ("a value" and "a list of 100 values" are mutually exclusive - you can either get one or 100, but not both.) When responding, please do so with an [edit] to your question to clarify what you're asking so everyone can see, rather than in a comment.

Comment: TrialOne is two columns that contain either 0, 1, or 2. I want to carry out above code 100 times, and record each outcome separately as a list, so I have a list of 100 numbers.

Comment: Put that information into your question, rather than in a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following snippet (adjust it for your particular range and worksheet naming)

```
Sub GenerateRandomList()
    Dim loop_ctr As Integer
    For loop_ctr = 1 To 100
        Range("A" & loop_ctr) = "=INT(RAND()*3+1)-1"
        Calculate
    Next loop_ctr
End Sub
```

Open the new Excel Worksheet, put the code in the Sheet1 VBA code module and run this sample. Please note that this solution is far from the optimum, but it's pertinent to your request. Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Hi, I just tried it and I get Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed. What does that mean??

Comment: Please see the added instruction.

Comment: Hi, I think I asked the question misguidedly. I posted another question with more details, slightly different from this question. Do you mind taking a look? It's under the title 'VBA making a list of outcomes after 100 iterations': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436293/vba-making-a-list-of-outcomes-after-100-iterations Thank you!

Comment: I will take a look at your second submission. Would you please mark this question answered? Thanks and regards,